# Files.bat virus problem in usb

Tags: virus

My pendrive had a Files.bat virus and all my files been shortcut folder. When I opened my files all my images and some videos still can be opened. Then I copied to my desktop and format my pendrive. When I plug my other pendrive to the laptop, the pendrive infected with the files.bat virus...now my 4 pendrives had the files.bat virus.. Am I copied the virus too to the desktop?

Comment: It will be difficult to determine how the infection spread. It is likely on your desktop.

Comment: I see..thank you. But is it all my files,images and videos safe to keep it in my desktop and my usb? After been infected with the Files.bat virus?

Comment: There is no way for me to know. You need someone to look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

They can auto infect any USB stick you plug in. There's even ones that hide in the firmware of the stick and jump over without you knowing.